# the conditions in a loop are not working properly

Tags: c#

In this condition the if statement and the else if statement are not working properly.I am trying to build a hangman game, the problem is that when the guessed letter is correct and matches a letter in the word it increment the countToLoose and print countToLoose and at the same time it prints "That is a correct guess".

Can someone please fix the title of the question to proper title because I can't think of other one.

```
public static string GuessTheLetter(string word)
{
    //List<string> _guessed = new List<string>();
    char[] charctersWord = word.ToLower().ToCharArray();
    int countToLoose = 0;
    
    while (countToLoose != 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a letter");
        string theGuessedLetter = Console.ReadLine();
        theGuessedLetter.ToLower();
    
        //_guessed.Add(theGuessedLetter);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < charctersWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!theGuessedLetter.ToLower().Equals(charctersWord[i])) 
            {
                countToLoose++ ;
                Console.WriteLine(countToLoose);
                break;
            }
            else if(String.Equals(theGuessedLetter.ToLower(), charctersWord) == true)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine("That is a correct guess");
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    return "";
}
```

Comment: You are checking if ALL letters in the word are equal to the input letter. If even one is different you are incrementing `countToLoose`. What you should do instead is see if the letter exists at all in the word only then decide the logic (so it has to be outside the loop)

Comment: "at the same time" - nope... not in the same iteration. Different iterations, for different letters. I suggest you step through the code in a debugger. (Hint: just because the guessed letter doesn't match the *first* letter of the word doesn't mean it doesn't match *any* letters...)

Comment: Just out of experience and habit: `while (countToLoose != 5)` - make this `< 5`

Comment: Instead of `theGuessedLetter.ToLower().Equals(charctersWord[i])`, you should prefer `theGuessedLetter.Equals(charctersWord[i], CultureInfo.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` (and similat for teh other comparison. The notion of "case-insensitive compare" can be difficult depending on the culture.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are comparing theGuessedLetter with each character from the array charctersWord, so although the word contains your guessed char, countToLoose gets incremented by charctersWord's length - 1.

Also, theGuessedLetter should be a char instead of string:

```
char theGuessedLetter = Console.ReadLine()[0];
```

instead of

```
string theGuessedLetter = Console.ReadLine();
```

And you could use String.Contains instead of the for loop. I also introduce a new variable, userWon, to get to know if the user guesses the letter:

```
bool userWon = false
while (countToLoose != 5 and !userWon)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a letter");
        string theGuessedLetter = Console.ReadLine();
        if (charctersWord.Contains(theGuessedLetter.ToLower()))
        {
             userWon = true;
        }
        countToLoose++;
}
```

And, after, you can check if the user guessed the letter to show the message:

```
if (userWon)
{
     Console.WriteLine("That is a correct guess");
}
```

Comment: that was very helpful and informative.thanks very much

Comment: Glad to help! I also wonder the logic of your game, btw. As far as I know, hangman game gives you n chances to guess the full word, not just a letter from it. Maybe it's some kind of initial homework?

Answer (score -2):

try this it will work fine. you are not doing incorrect way.

```
public static string GuessTheLetter(string word)
{
    //List<string> _guessed = new List<string>();
    char[] charctersWord = word.ToLower().ToCharArray();
    int countToLoose = 0;
    
    while (countToLoose != 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a letter");
        string theGuessedLetter = Console.ReadLine();
        theGuessedLetter.ToLower();
    
        //_guessed.Add(theGuessedLetter);
        bool guess=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < charctersWord.Length; i++)
        {
            
             if(String.Equals(theGuessedLetter.ToLower(), charctersWord) == true)
            {
                guess = true;
                 break;
                
            }
        }
        if (guess) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is a correct guess");
                countToLoose++ ;
                Console.WriteLine(countToLoose);
                break;
            }
    }
    
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Why increment countToLoose when the guess is right and not when it's wrong?

Comment: I don't know as the mention in above that if guess is right then increment the countToLoose